# Setting superscript color for \thanks

Tags: color, superscripts

Could someone please tell me how can I modify the color of superscript (near author name) which refers to \thanks? In the following example I would like the "*" symbol to be colored (both, the one on top of the page as well as the bottom one). I tried wrapping \thanks with \textcolor{} but it only changes the color of the top *

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}


\title{My Title}
\author{Name Surname\thanks{Thanks} }


\begin{document}
\maketitle

\end{document}
```

Thanks.
ML

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{color}
\title{My Title}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% two patches!
\patchcmd\maketitle{\normalfont\@thefnmark}{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}{}{\fail}
\patchcmd\maketitle{\normalfont\@thefnmark}{\normalfont\color{red}\@thefnmark}{}{\fail}
\makeatother

\author{Name Surname\thanks{Thanks} }


\begin{document}

\maketitle

\end{document}
```